# Googletest error. Not able to include : #include < gtest/gtest.h> in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal, googletest

I am working on VS code and I have cloned googletest from Git, I am working on VS code and worked the commands on terminal. I am trying to implement googletest in my test_deque.cc file. My test_deque.cc also includes a deque.h file. 
I have combined my test_deque.cc , deque.cc and googletest all in the same folder but I still get an error in my first line of test_deque.cc : Not able to include path #include < gtest/gtest.h>. How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `gtest.h` file located? What is your include path?

Comment: try using `#include "gtest/gtest.h"` if it is in the same folder as the source code you're compiling. refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename?rq=1